# Does Activity Recognition Transition API work on Wear OS?

Tags: android, wear-os, activity-recognition

I thought the Activity Recognition Transition API didn't work on Wear OS.
Does Wear OS support the Activity Recognition Transition API?

I checked whether the Activity Recognition Transition API works on Wear OS devices by referring to this site:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions

"task.addOnSuccessListener" handles success, but unfortunately ActivityTransitionResult never fires the event.